# How should I format digital signatures?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, signature, dsa

I'm working on implementing DSA digital signature algorithm. I understand the algorithm itself, one thing I don't really understand is how should my message look after it was signed?

For example, I have a text file that I'd like to sign and send to someone else. Where should I put the generated keys for verifying the signature, and how should I parse this message to verify the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PKCS#7](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2129) is your friend.

Update: I forgot to mention, that [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) (Cryptographic Message Syntax) is an evolution of PKCS#7.

Answer (score 2):

Eugene's link should answer your question. I will add one thing: Don't expect any actual security from your implementation of DSA. If you want the information secure, use an already-written DSA implementation. When not expertly written, crypto primitives can be terribly insecure.